# Show one content at a time in ng repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/asmKj/1/) where I want to expand only one item at a time. I am not able to figure out the condition for this. Appreciate it if someone can point out what I might be missing.

```
function sample ($scope) {

    $scope.procedures = [
        {
            definition: 'Procedure 1',
            discharged: 23
        },
        {
            definition: 'Procedure 2',
            discharged: 2
        },
        {
            definition: 'Procedure 3',
            discharged: 356
        }
    ];
}


<ul class="procedures" ng-app ng-controller="sample">
    <li ng-repeat="procedure in procedures">
        <h4><a href="#" ng-click="showDetails = ! showDetails">{{procedure.definition}}</a></h4>
         <div class="procedure-details" ng-class="{ 'hidden': ! showDetails }">
            <p>Number of patient discharges: {{procedure.discharged}}</p>
         </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you want to hide other elements?

Comment: Yes. Expand only one item at a time.

Comment: You could add a specific `showDetails` for each item

Comment: You should add a single global reference to store currently opened item. Then after every click you could simply close the last item at the beginning and then open the clicked one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to store the previous selected Index to get things working .

**html:**

```
<ul class="procedures" ng-app ng-controller="sample">
  <li ng-repeat="procedure in procedures">
    <h4><a href="#" ng-click="fireIt($index)">{{procedure.definition}}</a></h4>
    <div class="procedure-details" ng-class="{'hidden': !(curr == $index && showDetails)}">
      <p>Number of patient discharges: {{procedure.discharged}}</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**code:**

```
function sample($scope) {
  $scope.showDetails = true;
  $scope.fireIt = function(index) {
    $scope.curr = index;
    if($scope.prevIndex == index){  -- (1)
     $scope.showDetails = !$scope.showDetails; return;
    }
    $scope.prevIndex = index ;
    if(!$scope.showDetails) $scope.showDetails=!$scope.showDetails; -- (2)
  }
  $scope.procedures = [{
    definition: 'Procedure 1',
    discharged: 23
  }, {
    definition: 'Procedure 2',
    discharged: 2
  }, {
    definition: 'Procedure 3',
    discharged: 356
  }];
}
```

working sample up **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/asmKj/1192/)** for grabs .

**Note :** Quoted points (1) & (2) are key .

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the state for each procedure. Or you could put the procedure definition in your variable, something like :

```
<ul class="procedures" ng-app ng-controller="sample">
  <li ng-repeat="procedure in procedures">
    <h4><a href="#" ng-click="showDetails = showDetails ? undefined : procedure.definition">{{procedure.definition}}</a></h4>
    <div class="procedure-details" ng-class="{ 'hidden': ! (showDetails && showDetails == procedure.definition) }">
      <p>Number of patient discharges: {{procedure.discharged}}</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="procedures" ng-app ng-controller="sample">
    <li ng-repeat="procedure in procedures">
        <h4><a href="#" ng-click="clickLink($index)">{{procedure.definition}}</a></h4>
         <div class="procedure-details" ng-class="{ 'hidden': ! procedure.showDetail }">
            <p>Number of patient discharges: {{procedure.discharged}}</p>
         </div>
    </li>
</ul>

function sample ($scope) {

        $scope.clickLink = function(idx){
        for(var i=0;i<$scope.procedures.length;i++){
        if(i != idx)
            $scope.procedures[i].showDetail = false;
        else
            $scope.procedures[i].showDetail = true;
      }
    }
    $scope.procedures = [
        {
            definition: 'Procedure 1',
            discharged: 23,
            showDetail:false
        },
        {
            definition: 'Procedure 2',
            discharged: 2,
            showDetail:false
        },
        {
            definition: 'Procedure 3',
            discharged: 356,
            showDetail:false
        }
    ];
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot make any changes to the JSON format of $scope.procedures.

Answer (score 0):

You can define an activeItem variable in the controller to hold the item to be shown. Then, you should assign the index of the element you click to that variable:

```
ng-click="showDetails = ! showDetails; $parent.activeItem = $index"
```

Then, you should check both values to show an item:

```
ng-class="{ 'hidden': ! ( showDetails && $parent.activeItem == $index )}"
```

Check out the jsfiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/asmKj/1190/

Comment: Not hiding other procedure when I click on different procrdure

Comment: Again issue is Procedure-1, click on procedure-2 and now again click on procedure-1 it is not showing.

Comment: I'm checking it out

Comment: Is the size of procedures constant? Because as other users implied, a status for each procedure must be held. If you are not going to change the original JSON, you can create another list that holds their status'.